# C# foreach won't stop displaying "Player 1 perdio"

Tags: c#, winforms

Im currently working on a snake/Tron game with C# Windows form, i have some code for when to check if one snake has tocuhed the other one or bumped into a wall.

```
private void checkEndGame()
      {
            Boolean endGame = false;

            foreach(Point trail in bothtrail)
            {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(trail, new Size(15, 15));

                if (p2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(rect) && p2trail.Count > 1)
                {
                    tmr1.Stop();
                    endGame = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Player 1 perdio"); 
                }
                else if (p1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(rect) && p1trail.Count > 1)
                {
                    tmr1.Stop();
                    endGame = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Player 2 perdio"); //Wont Stop Showing Message Box
                }
            }

                if (p1.Left < 0 || p1.Top < 0 || p1.Left > this.Width || p1.Top > this.Height)
                {
                    tmr1.Stop();
                    endGame = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Player1 perdio");
                }

                else if (p2.Left < 0 || p2.Top < 0 || p2.Left > this.Width || p2.Top > this.Height)
                {
                    tmr1.Stop();
                    endGame = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Player2 perdio");
                }

                if (endGame)
                {
                    newGame();
                }
        }
```

Once it runs the first time and resets with `newGame();` the message box for the `if` and `else if` will continue to show nonstop. I have tried putting some breaks but I get the same result.

Should I be using `continue;` instead?

Comment: `newGame(); break;`

Comment: `break` is definitely a good choice to add. also consider `return` values

Comment: Is code formatted wrong or something? To me it looks like `newGame()` is outside the foreach.

Comment: @jmoon is right, the code is so badly formatted that is barely readable and it's outside.

Comment: @Gusman not me, Sach was the one to point it out

Comment: Lol, yes, you're right XD. Too late, time to go to bed.

Comment: I changed the format to the correct one Im using,  sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the condition for `endGame` after the `foreach` loop and break condition after in `if` statement in `foreach` loop. Try following:

```
    private void checkEndGame()
    {
        var endGame = false;

        foreach (Point trail in bothtrail)
        {
            var rect = new Rectangle(trail, new Size(15, 15));

            if (p2.Bounds.IntersectsWith(rect) && p2trail.Count > 1)
            {
                tmr1.Stop();
                endGame = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Player 1 perdio");
                break;
            }
            else if (p1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(rect) && p1trail.Count > 1)
            {
                tmr1.Stop();
                endGame = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Player 2 perdio"); //Wont Stop Showing Message Box
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!endGame)
        {

            if (p1.Left < 0 || p1.Top < 0 || p1.Left > this.Width || p1.Top > this.Height)
            {
                tmr1.Stop();
                endGame = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Player1 perdio");
            }

            else if (p2.Left < 0 || p2.Top < 0 || p2.Left > this.Width || p2.Top > this.Height)
            {
                tmr1.Stop();
                endGame = true;
                MessageBox.Show("Player2 perdio");
            }
        }


        if (endGame)
        {
            newGame();
        }
    }
```

In addition to this, you have lot of scope of code reusability here. You may want to create a common method something similar to below:

```
private bool _gameEnded = false;

private void EndGame(string player)
{
   tmr1.Stop();
   _gameEnded = true;
   MessageBox.Show($"{player} perdio");
}
```

And then call this method from `checkEndGame` wherever applicable.